# Why the following python code gives -5 as a result

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I tried the following code:

```
x = 4

b = ~x
print(b)
```

When I print b the result is `-5`

`4` in binary is `100`, shouldn't `~4` be `011`?

Comment: Why should only the first 3 bits be inverted? (What if you used a 4-bit number?)

Comment: Explanation in detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement (Look at the tables on top right).

Comment: You're right if 4 was represented as just `100`. In python, it will be represented as `0000 0100` which is the 8-bit representation of 4. Which means that `~4` will be `1111 1011` which is `-5` according to the decimal of signed 2's complement

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question just because OP does not know the answer. Are infinte sign bits all that common? Just try `bin(~4 & 0x7)` and you'll get it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take your time to read the Help Center if you haven't done it yet.

Comment: Thanks Anwarvic. Now it makes sense.

Comment: @eaperdomo: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

`4` indeed is `100` in binary, but `~4` is not just `011`, it is `11111...111011` with enough leading `1` bits to fill the representation of the type in memory.

In Python, integers do not have a fixed size, to there should be an infinite number of leading `1` bits. The trick is to use the two's complement representation for these numbers and use the equivalence: `~a` <=> `-a-1`, so `~4` is effectively `-5`.